# UIViewController with custom UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to make e.g. UIViewController use a custom UIVIew class?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where are you getting this UIView class? Is it from a nib? Or have you created a class which is a subclass of UIView?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Just create your custom class that inherits UIView, open interface builder, open the ViewController xib file, select the view, and change the Class on the View Identity tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom view in the Interface Builder and reuse it in a Controller. I just found the answer at the bottom of this post:
http://fdiv.net/2011/10/29/reusable-views-ios

Download the example, there is no code in the files, only the connections used in IB and the skeletton of the custom view.